# recursively log all children of all children in dom

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodevalue

I'm trying to get all the children recursively in the DOM. I've looked at some other examples but they were a little too excessive for what I'm trying to do. Basically I just want to grab all the nodeValues of the nodes on a page assuming they look something like the following.

```
child
   child
       child
-------------------
child
    child
-------------------
child
-------------------
child
   child
      child
-------------------
```

my current code is as follows but it only scoops down one layer and assumes that a child would not have another X children. I don't want to keep making for loops so I was hoping someone could introduce me to a good recursive method instead?

```
   //check all children inside a child
          for(let j = 0; j < children[i].length; j++){
              console.log(children[i][j])
                      }
                  }
```

Comment: *assuming they look something like the following* None of that is HTML. If these are elements on the page, can you post their structure in HTML syntax?

Comment: you want to look at *recursion*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.querySelectorAll('body *') should return every DOM element in the body and flatten them out if that is what you need.

If you are looking for a recursive function

```js
var elements = [];
var recursiveFindChildren = function(el) {
  for (let i = 0, iLength = el.children.length; i<iLength; i++) {
    elements.push(el.children[i]);
    if (el.children[i].children.length) recursiveFindChildren(el.children[i]);
  }
  return elements;
}

recursiveFindChildren(document.body)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for